# Macbook Pro - Outlook ver 16: Importing OLM into main Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macbook-pro, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to import a huge OLM backup file from an old MacBook Pro to a new one for a client and am running into a slight issue...

I am able to import into Outlook, however it creates an Archived OLM set of folders under the On My Computer folder. So the problem is that the old Inbox (archived) is not in the main inbox where the new emails come into.

I've tried moving, copying, etc. but nothing will put them all in the same folders (meaning all emails both new and archived in the same folder).

Does anyone know of a way to do what I need to do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to be by design that the imported items will be put in “on my computer”. Did you get any error message when moving/copying the emails?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried doing that and did not get any error. But I then have multiple folders where sets of inboxes, deleted, etc.

Comment: It seems that no way can take these emails back to INBOX folder. But in Outlook for Windows, we can do this.